# How to change button text to Wait, check for content change then reset button text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, setinterval

I have only recently started using jQuery so any additional guidance would always be appreciated.

I’m trying to add some nice UI features to my site, specifically to change a clicked button text to "wait" to show that the site is doing something. If the button calls a page load, it will say "Wait" until the next page has loaded - no problem... But sometimes a button may call a popup modal which the user could cancel and return to the page. 
Because the user could return, I need to check if a popup modal has appeared after a button has been clicked, if so at that point change the button text back.

This code works for me (sort of) but when I click the button a second time, the button changes to "wait..." but then it will not change back.

here is a jsfiddle to try and explain further:
http://jsfiddle.net/BU3SW/3/
(I'm afraid that the close is not working in the fiddle either so I'm not fully able to show you.)

This is my button:

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Create</a>
```

And my jQuery:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        v = $this.html(),
        s = 'go';

        //create a function to reset the text
        function fix() {
            $this.html(v);
            s = 'stop';
        }

    //check we are not clicking on green button
    if (!$this.hasClass('green')) {
        //change the text to wait...
        $this.html('wait...');

        //we will use a setInterval to keep checking every second
        //but only if "s" is still 'go' which means we are still waiting.
        if (s === 'go') {
            var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                if ($('.modalWrapper').html() !== '') {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    fix();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

    }

});
```

thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
Will.

Comment: In your real situation, what is it you are waiting for?  Generally there are callbacks in jquery which can be used which are a lot cleaner than using `setInterval`.

Comment: There is only one real problem I have with my current code, which is that when you click an ajax button, you may need to wait 3, 5, 10 seconds for an HTML partial to be displayed. During that time the end user may not know that anything is happening. To save having to reload the entire page when a modal is cancelled, I just wanted to do something to switch the text back but only once the modal is on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your real situation, as described in the comments, is the use of `ajax`, you should use a callback, not `setInterval`.

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.html('wait...');

    $.ajax({...
        success: function(){
            $this.html("go");        
        }
    });
});
```

Or something like this:

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.html('wait...');

    $.ajax({...}).done(function(){
        $this.html("go");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello @James Montagne, I'm happy to accept this as the correct answer because this is the correct approach, unfortunately I don't believe it will help me in my situation. My Ajax request is not included as part of the button click method - what I really wanted was a standalone way of making this happen which is why I never mentioned Ajax initially. I've made a few changes and have managed to sort the second click issue, once I get it finished I'll update my post to share my work with anyone else looking for the same - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Gonzales (jquery team) said :

> .html() doesn't have a callback because it is synchronous, so any code
>   executed after the .html() call will definitely occur after the html
>   is set.

So you just have to write something like

```
$('.button').on('click', function () {
    $(this).html("Wait...");
    $(".modalWrapper").html("bla bla bla");
    $(this).html("initial text");
});
$('.cancel').on('click', function () {
    $(".modalWrapper").html('');
});
```

You can add a mechanism to check if `modalwrapper` has allready benn opened, and your done.

Comment: This is fairly pointless as the browser will not update the label until after the function completes.  Your `$(this).html("Wait...");` will be replaced before it is ever displayed.

Comment: Hi @Scott, I started with something like this. in my jQuery I have an if statement `if (s === 'go')` which is checking if the modal is open but that is what I can't quite get working. The first time works but when I empty the modal, the next time I call the same modal, the 'Wait...' text just sticks and will not revert back. I thought it was something to do with the clearInterval but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

you do

```
$('.modalWrapper').html($('.partial').html());
$('.partial').html('');
```

then the second time if ($('.modalWrapper').html() !== '') will always be true
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BU3SW/4/)